# Sites not accessible after running permission fix, possible DNS error?

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, vps

I have a problem with my current VPS server running CentOS 6 and is managed with WHM and cPanel. All my websites were being created from WHM and are located in the /home directory (ownership: mysite:mysite owns mysite/)

Recently, I ran a permission fix to make sure all the sites are being owned by the correct users and user groups. The script that I used to run the fix is: https://knowledgebase.servint.net/questions/674/A+Script+for+Fixing+File+Permissions

After running the fix, my sites are not accessible anymore though I'm not sure what is wrong here. It's even more weird because I can still perform other actions such as ssh'ing to the server, logging in the WHM and site's cPanel (so not a firewall issue) - it is just only the site itself that can't be accessed (not found error).

I highly doubt that this is something wrong with the DNS setting. However, I did check the DNS Zone Editor within one of my sites' cPanel and it still got it correctly.

So now I have no idea how to fix it. Any help/guess is very much appreciated.

Comment: Is every single site broken or are some working?

Comment: Everything stopped working to be exact :)

Answer (score 3):

### It is a file permissions/ownership issue.

You ran a script to change the permissions (and ownership - look at what the script actually does) of the files served up by your webserver.  After doing so, your webserver will no longer serve up those files.

Now, you actually need to fix the permissions back after your "permission fix" script broke them.

Do note that ServInt, the publisher of that script, states that it is only to be used if you use FastCGI or SuPHP, and strongly recommends backing everything up before running the script.

I sincerely hope you took their advice.

### This has absolutely nothing to do with DNS nor with your firewall.

You didn't change the DNS, nor did you change your firewall.
And there is no evidence that would even remotely hint to something wrong with either.